# Ethernet connection turns off when my Mac idles

Tags: network, ethernet, screensaver

I often leave my Mac for some time to do assorted tasks. When I return and log into the screensaver, I can't visit my homepage, Google, because the Ethernet connection has disconnected, requiring a few minutes to reestablish DHCP before I can Google again. Is there a way to keep the Ethernet connection alive while my computer idles?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.4 Mountain Lion x64;
on a 2013 MacBook Pro 15";
with an official Apple Mini DVI to Gigabit Ethernet adapter;
plugged into a good cat5 cable.

Comment: `Spotlight -> System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Power Adapter -> Computer sleep -> Never`

and

`Energy Saver -> Battery -> Computer sleep -> Never`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with the wifi I use.

It would disconnect me after certain time of inactivity.

So when downloading big stuff it would disconnect me, unless I was active on the computer/web.

To prevent wifi been disconnected during long downloads or me not interacting with it:

In Terminal I entered following:

```
ping -i600 google.com
```

That would send a ping to Google than wait 600 seconds to send another ping and on and on...till I hit the <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it.

That will tell wifi I am active so it will stay up all the time.

The 600 sec (10 minutes) is a choice, and it worked for me.
In my case it was the WiFi service provider that cut me off after been inactive for a while.

Comment: When you're ready to stop this, press Control+C.

Comment: While that will work, you really shouldn't have to do that. Call it a short term solution to a long term problem

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be because the location may be set to automatic. I would try the method here: https://wccftech.com/fix-internet-not-working-after-waking-mac/ - Use the method titled "Fix Internet Not Working Issue After Waking Your Mac Up From Sleep" - Just thought I would share if those are still looking for options to try